# ¿Hay alguna manera de enlazar búsquedas del CORDE o del NTLLE?

Tags: rae, recursos

Pues eso. Básicamente, la RAE tiene a disposición del público dos* pedazo de recursos: el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html), un corpus del español escrito en los últimos 10 siglos; y el [NTLLE](http://buscon.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle), un "diccionario de diccionarios" que permite consultar la evolución de una palabra desde su primera aparición en un diccionario hasta hoy.

<sub>* Junto con el CREA y resto de *corpus* del [banco de datos de la RAE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos), que tampoco son moco de pavo, pero yo al menos no los utilizo tanto.</sub>

Utilizo mucho ambos recursos a la hora de buscar respuestas para las dudas que surgen sobre el lenguaje (tanto las aquí planteadas, como las mías personales). Pero por la manera en que están diseñadas las páginas anteriores, me surge un problema: no sé cómo **compartir con otras personas, mediante un enlace, los resultados de la búsqueda que he realizado**.

Si yo quiero compartir los resultados de buscar en Google "perico", puedo compartir este enlace: https://www.google.es/search?q=perico.
Si quiero compartir los resultados de buscar en el DLE "palote", puedo compartir este enlace: http://dle.rae.es/?w=palote.
Pero si quiero compartir los resultados de buscar en el CORDE "perico de los palotes"... ¿cómo puedo hacerlo? Más allá de copiar el texto de los resultados, o hacer una captura de pantalla. Copiar el enlace no sirve, pues depende de la sesión, y al pegar el enlace en otro dispositivo ya no funciona.

**¿Existe alguna manera de enlazar a una búsqueda en CORDE o NTLLE, de forma que se puedan compartir los resultados mediante un simple enlace?**

Comment: Acabo de fijarme en que el DIRAE usa [un script de Python](https://github.com/vibragiel/glotologia/blob/master/origenes/origenes.py) para obtener la primera vez que una palabra aparece en un diccionario usando el NTLLE. Igual se podría modificar para poder obtener la lista completa de entradas de una consulta al NTLLE, y publicarlo en algún sitio que podamos enlazar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El CORDE realmente no mantiene una sesión de usuario (como hace el NTLLE), y sus resultados se pueden enlazar. Por ejemplo, si busco "perico" en el CORDE puedo enlazar la pantalla con el resumen de resultados:

http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=perico&autor=&titulo=&ano1=1600&ano2=1800&medio=1000&pais=9&tema=1000 (casos de "perico" entre 1600 y 1800 en España).

El enlace contiene lo necesario para repetir la búsqueda: el texto de la misma y los parámetros establecidos. En la pantalla enlazada se puede ver el texto "7 casos en 4 documentos". Desde ahí se puede acceder a las estadísticas o a la recuperación de ejemplos (que es la parte que suele interesar). Esta pantalla de recuperación de ejemplos no se puede enlazar, pero si entras en un ejemplo, el enlace que se genera sí se puede copiar:

[http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=4&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=231017\010\C000O23102017105335787.1192.1188&desc={B}+{I}+perico{|I},+en+{I}1600-1800{|I},+en+todos+los+medios,+en+{I}CORDE+{|I}+,+en+{I}ESPA%D1A+{|I}{|B}{BR}&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto4](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=4&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=231017%5C010%5CC000O23102017105335787.1192.1188&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20perico%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D1600-1800%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20,%20en%20%7BI%7DESPA%D1A%20%7B%7CI%7D%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto4)

De esta forma se puede enlazar un caso concreto. Además, en la pantalla del caso concreto vuelve a aparecer arriba el resumen de resultados y el botón para recuperar ejemplos, lo cual es útil si se ha accedido al ejemplo desde un enlace.

Con respecto al NTLLE, usa un sistema de sesión que expira a poco que dejes la cuenta sin usar por apenas unos minutos. He intentado ver si hay alguna forma de acceder a resultados de búsqueda o a casos concretos de aparición en algún diccionario específico, pero no ha habido forma. Además, te confirmo que para buscar el término de búsqueda, la petición que se envía al servidor es de tipo `POST`, con un `form` por debajo, por lo que no sería posible simular dicha consulta con un simple enlace. Una vez cargados los resultados, la petición que se hace para cargar la definición correspondiente a un diccionario concreto sí es de tipo `GET`, pero no incluye el término de búsqueda. Esa llamada tiene esta pinta:

http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltNavegacion?numReg=4&diccionario=26&hoja=223&columna=2&creaCn=SI&operacion=14&sec=1.2.1.0.0.&

Si te fijas, contiene como parámetros el código del diccionario, la página y la columna a mostrar. Pero si intentas copiar esa dirección en el navegador, incluso si es dentro de la misma ventana en la que tienes una sesión activa, te muestra un error diciendo que "la petición está fuera de secuencia".

Comment: Walen, ya está la respuesta a lo del NTTLE. Si como dice Carlos es una _form_ con llamados _post/get_ va a ser técnicamente imposible reconstruir un llamado y obtener una respuesta con un simple _url_.

Comment: @DGaleano interesante, en España se suele decir "una URL", no "un URL". ¿Te hace una pregunta para saber qué forma sería la más adecuada, o qué motivos hay para cada caso? :-)

Comment: Aquí también casi todo el mundo dice **una** pero justo al escribir este comentario y luego de escribir _una url_ pensé que eso significa **Uniform Resource Locator** por lo que decidí que **locator=localizador** y por lo tanto masculino y en consecuencia lo edité. Hasta hace 2 minutos para mi era _una_ pero creo que lo voy a seguir usando en masculino.

Comment: @DGaleano claro, pero lo de "una URL" es por contracción de "una dirección URL", ¿no?

Comment: Puede ser, pero si lo piensas es redundante decir _The/an Uniform Resource Locator **Address/Link**._ En inglés solo se dice _the url_ o _an url_ Y a propósito URL no necesariamente es _web address_ ya que no solo puede ser http sino también ftp, mailto, etc.